# How to embedding variable in HTML with jbpm7 business Central?

Tags: jboss, jbpm

How to embedding variable in HTML with jbpm7 business Central ?

Comment: Could you elaborate more your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.